# Customized Contact Layout doesn’t appear when editing or creating a new contact

Tags: page-layout

I made changes to the standard **Contact Layout** to add new custom fields (and a bit of re-arranging). However, when I try to create a new contact (or edit an existing one), the layout is not the one I customized.

I’ve already been successful doing the same process for the standard **Lead Layout** but can’t figure out how to fix the **Contact Layout**. Oddly enough, the ‘*Preview As…*’ button shows the customized layout properly for both the *Details* and *Edit* pages. I’ve saved the layout multiple times.

I also checked the ‘*Page Layout Assignments*’; all profiles use **Contact Layout** except ‘*Minimum Access – Salesforce*’; it reads “*Not Assigned*.” I’m logged on as System Administrator.

Forgive me if this is a bit lengthy or unclear. I’ve been up to my eyeballs in fields, records, and values. Oh my!

Comment: Have you done a hard refresh in your browser, logged out and in again and/or turned off page caching via Session Management in Setup? (You have to scroll up in that page to find the setting)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already tried the first two, and found the cache settings under Session Setup. I didn't see any way to dump the cache, but I did disable all the options. Too bad it didn't work. Also, good tip to scroll up - that page dropped me at the bottom when it loaded.

Comment: [This](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000395970&type=1) anything to do with it?